# The use of both

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct 
My brothers and I each study science
Or
My brothers and I both study science

Comment: ...or how about "My brothers and I all study science." _Both_ usually indicates two people.

Comment: _Both_ means "all two"; it's restricted to duals.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is correct. Both sentences are wrong!

John Lawler is right and Cascabel's suggestion is perfect: in fact I think it's the only way to say what you're trying to say. *Both* can't be used for more than two people or things.

*Each* singles people (and things) out, whereas *all* groups them together. When the pronoun *each* is followed immediately by a verb, that verb is always singular. So "each study" breaks that rule. "I have two brothers. Each studies science" would be fine, but you can't add *yourself* because you end up with 'My brothers and I each studies science', which is awful!

"My brothers and I all study science" is perfect. By the way, you might also consider "We all study science, my brothers and I.'